# How to get the value of a single attribute from a HTML tag using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using this code to go though a list of p tags that is much longer that in my example with 1 or more span tags in it. I know even span tag from the list has the font-style attribute. I'm stuck trying to figure out if the specific span tag that I'm looking at font-style attribute has a value of italic. Is there a way to get the value of the font-style attribute or return a bool if the font-style is italic?

```
content = "<p dir="ltr">
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">a</span>
           </p>,
           <p dir="ltr">
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: italic; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">b</span>
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">c</span>
           </p>,
           <p dir="ltr">
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">d</span>
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: italic; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">e</span>
           </p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')

page = {}
ital = []
i = 1
p = 1
for par in soup:
    page[i] = {}
    for x in par.find_all('span'):
        if x['font-style'] == 'italic':  #stuck here trying to figure out if font-style value is italic or not
            ital.append(p)
        par = 'par_{}'.format(p)
        page[i].update({par:x.next})
        p += 1
    page[i].update({'ital':ital})
    ital = []
    i += 1
    p = 1
```

**UPDATE:**

my goal is to get all the content in between the span tags in order on `page` and know what part of the content is italic.

after running this  page should look like this

```
print(page)

{
    1: {'ital': [],
        'par_1':'a'},
    2: {'ital': [1],
        'par_1':'b',
        'par_2':'c'},
    3: {'ital': [2],
        'par_1':'d',
        'par_2':'e'}
}
```

currently this code prints

```
print(page)

{
    1: {'ital': [],
        'par_1':'a'},
    2: {'ital': [],
        'par_1':'b',
        'par_2':'c'},
    3: {'ital': [],
        'par_1':'d',
        'par_2':'e'}
}
```

Comment: Is the style really `italize`?  Because that's neither a standard CSS font-style nor an English word.

Comment: no i was too stressed  when I enter the ticket and didn't spell check. I'll fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the span tag is one attribute and that attribute's name is style. Everything else is a string within style. It is impossible to get the value of font-style attribute because it isn't a attribute.`if 'font-style: italic' in x['style']:` is how you check if font-style is italic or not. `x['style']` returns the value of the style attribute as a string. Then its just checking if the `'font-style: italic'` exists within the string that `x['style']` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use lambdas in BeautifulSoup's `find_all()` function. This example will find all `span` tags with '*italize*' in style attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''"<p dir="ltr">
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">a</span>
           </p>,
           <p dir="ltr">
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: italize; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">d</span>
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">b</span>
           </p>,
           <p dir="ltr">
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">c</span>
               <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: italize; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">d</span>
           </p>"'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

for span in soup.find_all('span', style=lambda s: 'italize' in s):
    print(span)
```

Prints:

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: italize; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">d</span>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: italize; background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">d</span>
```

Comment: Find_all extracts the span tags from the list with font-style: italize. I’m trying to keep the span tags in order because I want the content in between each span tag. Is there a way to check if the current span tag’s font-style is italize and return a true or false?